# % Tags Not Updating During Execution

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a `batch` file which modifies the environment variables the following:

```
setx -m MAVEN_HOME "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1"
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"
setx -m PATH "%PATH%%MAVEN_HOME%\bin"
PAUSE
```

It's basically an installation of `Maven`.

When I execute it as administrator it doesn't find the `MAVEN_HOME` variable the first time it is ran even though the variable has been set already. It results in a new entry called `\bin` instead of the `MAVEN_HOME` path prepended.

A second execution is required to make it work.

How do I fix the script so that it only needs to run once?

Comment: When you run `setx -m`, it updates the environment in the registry, but this change does not propagate to the currently running cmd.exe process that's running your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing double % to indicate that it's actually inside the String instead of a variable:

```
setx -m PATH "%PATH%%%MAVEN_HOME%%\bin"
```